# How do I know the concrete result after classification by dendrogram in scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I want to use scipy package to make a hierachical clustering.However, I only got the visulaization result after using dendrogram,
the image shows that:
[image]

The question is I want to know each sample's predicted label if I assume numbers of cluster at first. For example, if I draw a red line on this image(it means I assume there are 5 clusters at first), then I will

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

ytdist = np.array([662., 877., 255., 412., 996., 295., 468., 268., 400., 754., 564., 138., 219., 869., 669.])

#'single','complete','average'
linked = linkage(ytdist, 'single')
plt.figure()
dendrogram(linked, orientation='top', distance_sort='descending',show_leaf_counts=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import (
   linkage, fcluster, dendrogram
)
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Generate sample data

```
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.concatenate((
    np.random.uniform(30, 35, 5),
    np.random.uniform(40, 45, 5),
    np.random.uniform(50, 55, 5),
))
np.random.seed(42)
y = np.concatenate((
    np.random.uniform(40, 55, 5),
    np.random.uniform(30, 35, 5),
    np.random.uniform(35, 40, 5),
))
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x,'y': y})
plt.scatter(x, y);
```

[image]

Linkage and dendrogram

```
Z = linkage(df)
dn = dendrogram(Z);
```

[image]

We choose 3 clusters (you could use elbow method, for example) and we add the cluster label to the `df`

```
df['cluster_labels'] = fcluster(Z, 3, criterion='maxclust')
sns.scatterplot(x='x', y='y', hue='cluster_labels', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]